# Number of subset combinations with fixed size

Tags: combinatorics

I'd like to calculate the number of possible subsets with a fixed size. There is this practical example I have:

> There are 26 persons within a school class. I'd like to calculate the
>   number of possibilities to divide this group in subgroups of 5, 5, 5,
>   5 and 6 people.

**Approach**
(...is algorithmic, because my domain is Software Engineering :D)

I use a list to represent results: 
`#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6,... #23, #24, #25, #26`

The first 5 people in this representation are members of group 1, next bunch of 5 people are members of group 2 and so forth.

For permutation I shuffle the elements of this list. This creates results which are partially duplicates. E.g. `#5, #4, #3, #2, #1,... #23, #24, #25, #26`

So this is why want to calculate the number of possible results I could theoretically create by permutation.

**Calculation**

$$ \frac{\frac{26!}{5! \times 5! \times 5! \times 5! \times 6!}}{4!} = 112.551.245.286.480‬ $$

*Edit: Four groups of 5 people aren't distinguishable. Thanks to [@zipirovich](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3552663/752306)*

Comment: You should not use a dot to separate groups of three digits. A thin space is the only legal thing to add if you want to stick to what the SI brochure recommends.

Comment: Using dots to separate thousands is standard in many languages, including Italian, Norwegian, Spanish and Dutch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the four subgroups of five people each are distinguishable, then this is correct. By distinguishable I mean something like they are teams with names: "Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", and "Team 4". And you consider the case when persons A,B,C,D,E are in "Team 1" and persons F,G,H,I,J are in "Team 2" different from the case when  persons A,B,C,D,E are in "Team 2" and persons F,G,H,I,J are in "Team 1".

But if you don't need to distinguish those four groups of five people, then your number is too big. To account for these four groups being indistinguishable, you also need to divide by $4!$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great answer. Those four groups aren't distinguishable. I'll edit my post